# TSQL Whats the simplest way to perform this tiny SELECT query?

Tags: t-sql, select

I'm trying to figure out the cleanest way to perform some lookups.  I have an index table full of employees here, and then a larger ticket table that uses their EmployeeIDs in several places - who made the ticket, who last updated it, and who closed it.  I'm trying to figure out the easiest way to pull up each of their names in a SELECT query without doing a small subquery each time, which is what I'm doing right now.

I made this little exercise for myself to try and simplify the issue:

```
    CREATE TABLE NameLookup
    (
        NameIndex INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
        Name VARCHAR(10)
    );

    CREATE UNIQUE NONCLUSTERED INDEX NameIdx ON dbo.NameLookup ([Name])
    WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF);

    CREATE TABLE BunchaNames
    (
        PK INT PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED IDENTITY(1,1),
        NameOne INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.NameLookup(NameIndex),
        NameTwo INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.NameLookup(NameIndex),
        NameThree INT FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES dbo.NameLookup(NameIndex)
    );

    INSERT INTO NameLookup(Name)
    VALUES ('Bill'), ('Phil'), ('Jill'), ('Gil'), ('Fred');
```

So now, I want to SELECT NameOne, NameTwo, and NameThree from BunchaNames and display the names in NameLookup.  Whats the easiest/correct way to do this?  Is it this?  Many thanks for any help!

```
    SELECT (SELECT Name FROM NameLookup WHERE NameIndex = bn.NameOne) AS NameOne,
            (SELECT Name FROM NameLookup WHERE NameIndex = bn.NameTwo) AS NameTwo,
            (SELECT Name FROM NameLookup WHERE NameIndex = bn.NameThree) AS NameThree
    FROM BunchaNames bn
```

Comment: Since there is no relation b/w `namelookup` and `bunchanames` ... your query looks correct to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use left joins

```
select n1.Name as firstName, n2.Name as secondName, n3.Name as thirdName
from BunchaNames as bn
left join NameLookup as n1 
     on bn.NameOne=n1.nameIndex
left join NameLookup as n2  
     on bn.NameTwo=n2.nameIndex
left join NameLookup as n3  
     on bn.NameThree=n3.nameIndex
```

Comment: Thanks, Kyra!  That makes a lot of sense.